# Map with record as key - how to check if key exists in Erlang

Tags: erlang, maps, record

I would like to make a map, that has a record as key and list as a value, but I have a problem with checking if a similar key already exists - or rather I don't know how to make it work in Erlang.

I have a record with three vales, and I need to check if there is a key in the map that has at least one value equal.

I see it that way:

```
-record(r, {A, B, C}).
addRecord(newA, newB, newC, Map) ->
  case maps:is_key(#r{A = newA, B = _, C = _}, Map) or maps:is_key(#r{A = _, B = newB, C = _}, Map) or maps:is_key(#r{A = _, B = _, C = newC}, Map) of
    true -> threo("...")
    _ -> maps:put(#r(A = newA, B = newB, C = newC), [], Map)
end.
```

My idea was to give _ as "any value" in maps:is_key but that doesn't work in Erlang.

Do you have any idea how to check it (possibly easily)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no particularly cheap way to do it. You may need to check all of the map's keys. The simple way is

```
lists:any(fun(X) -> 
              is_record(X, r) andalso 
              (X#r.A == newA orElse X#r.B == newB orElse X#r.C == newC) 
          end, 
          maps:keys(Map))
```

(I used `A` etc. as in your example, to make it simpler to compare, but field names have to be atoms, so they should be `a` or `'A'`).

A cheaper way is to use [`maps:iterator`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#iterator-1): less memory and can stop early if you find a suitable key. But the code would be significantly more complicated.